# Programmatically starting the 'Add Account' activity in Android 2.2

Tags: android, authentication, android-intent, android-2.2-froyo

I've been experimenting with the Android SDK over the past few days, in readiness to write an App for the store, however I've run across a bit of a problem.

The App I'll be writing requires that the user has a Google account associated with the phone. Retrieving and making use of the Auth token etc was not a problem, however I would like to be able to show the activity that a user would normal reach by going through the menus Settings->Accounts->Add Account.

Now through experimentation I've been able to launch this activity from the shell using the following command.

```
am start -n com.google.android.gsf/.login.AccountIntroActivity
```

I'm having trouble performing the same action in JAVA using the Intent class.

Would anyone be able to tell me firstly whether or not this can be done via JAVA, and secondly how I could go about it please?

If I have to settle for the Sync Settings screen then I will (this can be achieved through the Settings.ACTION_SYNC_SETTINGS intent), however it'd be quite nice to be able to direct the user straight to the required screen.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check out the [ACTION_ADD_ACCOUNT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_ADD_ACCOUNT)

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_ADD_ACCOUNT));
```

Comment: My thanks - that is one step closer to what I'm trying to achieve, however to quote our Jedi masters - 'this is not the Activity you are looking for'.

It is the next step in the chain I am trying to invoke - part of the Setup Wizard - the activity that appears when you click on the 'Google' account symbol. If this is impossible, I'll stick with the ACTION_ADD_ACCOUNT answer. Thanks

Comment: Probably it's impossible because I don't see on the linked resource. And that is the only page that describes the settings globals.

Comment: That's what I feared - I imagine access to the component I'm calling above from adb shell (com.google.android.gsf/.login.AccountIntroActivity) is probably restricted some how.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
public static void addGoogleAccount(final Activity activity) {
    final AccountManager accountMgr = AccountManager.get(activity);
    accountMgr.addAccount("com.google", "my_auth_token", null, null, activity, null, null);
}
```

Comment: Thanks markjan - I'll check that out once I've got my SDK setup again.

Comment: "my_auth_token" is it a valid auth token type for Google account? If no, then can you please tell me valid auth token type for adding Google account?

Answer (score 3):

Android Account Manager provides an API to add account. (google or other account types)

public AccountManagerFuture addAccount (String accountType, String authTokenType, String[] requiredFeatures, Bundle addAccountOptions, Activity activity, AccountManagerCallback callback, Handler handler)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html

Answer (score 3):

the answer for the above question by providing EXTRA_ACCOUNT_TYPES in the intent extra data. and set the value to "com.google" in order to alert the activity:

```
public static void startAddGoogleAccountIntent(Context context){
Intent addAccountIntent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_ADD_ACCOUNT)
.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
addAccountIntent.putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_ACCOUNT_TYPES, new String[] {"com.google"});
context.startActivity(addAccountIntent); }
```

Comment: I tested and it works well, this answer should be accepted

Answer (score 2):

For recent Androids using `adb` you can do:

```
adb shell am start -a android.settings.ADD_ACCOUNT_SETTINGS \
                   -n com.android.settings/.accounts.AddAccountSettings
```

(You’ll still have to select what account type you’d like though)

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion! Is it possible to add/pass the pre-determined values to the Android Account Manager? For example in a `davdroid-config.json` ?

Answer (score 1):

The clue is in your shell command:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClassName( "com.google.android.gsf", "com.google.android.gsf.login.AccountIntroActivity" );
    context.startActivity( intent );
```